# File Modified After Upload

Tags: office-365, file-upload

After uploading a file, using the single file upload, the form displays to the user allowing customer columns to be edited. However, when we click save we get an error message saying the file was modified.

What's interesting about this error, is it only happens to general SharePoint Users my Global Admin Account seems unaffected.

Our environment : SharePoint 2013 / Office 365

[image: Screen shot of the error.]

Comment: do you have a workflow running behind the scenes?

Comment: You got it! I forgot I had one running in the background. I have a workflow defined to notify the original author if someone made a modification to the document. Any suggestions on how I can make the workflow wait till the additional column information is filled in?

Comment: Try making your workflow to be version 2010.  We had the exact same problem with a 2013 workflow, but when we recreated it using the 2010 version, it worked.  (No good reason why!)